# Error trying to authenticate with FCM servers when sending message using Firebase Admin SDK in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

When I try to send to send an FCM notification to a topic I get the following error...

> Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM
> servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has
> the proper permissions.

I am using a brand new generated service account key and pointing to it correctly. I have confirmed that the path to the key is correct. I have also enabled Cloud Messaging for the project.

```
const { messaging } = require('firebase-admin');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

console.log(process.cwd());

async function run() {
  try {
    var serviceAccount = require("/Users/myUser/src/my_project/node_admin/my_project-5617a-firebase-adminsdk-lwpk6-5dad9000e0.json");
    const topic = 'all';
  
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });
  
    const payload = {
      notification: {
          title: "Test1234",
          body: "body",
          sound: 'test-sound.wav'
      }
    };
  
    var options = {
        priority: "high"
    }
    
    await admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic , payload , options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}


run();
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello i was copy code and run --> it working
so i think you can check path of file auth json

```
var serviceAccount = require("/Users/myUser/src/my_project/node_admin/my_project-5617a-firebase-adminsdk-lwpk6-5dad9000e0.json");
```

good luck!

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).